# Android - determine start and end date of week

Tags: android

I have written simple code for getting start and end date of a week. It goes like

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
start = new DateTime(calendar.getTime());

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
end = new DateTime(calendar.getTime());
```

`start` and `end` are `DateTime` from `joda time`. `week` and `year` are parameters.

The problem is that when I debug this piece of code, it's working. When not debugging, the `start` and `end` is set for current week. To be clear, I have to debug line by line not to only run app in debug mode. Sometimes the year is set but start and end dime are the same. I have no idea what could cause that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I could figure out what was the problem, but if someone is looking for a really easy way to get start and end date of any week in any year you can use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
DateTime start = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(week).withYear(year).withDayOfWeek(1); //1 - monday

DateTime end = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(week).withYear(year).withDayOfWeek(7); //7 - sunday
```